# Do Multiple Asyncronous Invocations REQUIRE unique userStates?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, callback, state

I'm working on a C# application in which I set up a few asynchronous function calls using delegates. These calls will be subject to multiple-invocations, so I have to use the overload of the delegate's `BeginInvoke` method which takes a `userState` argument; e.g.:

```
callerDelegate.BeginInvoke([fn_args...], callback, userState)
```

On the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern Overview page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx), it says about userState:

> There are potentially two overloads
>   for the asynchronous operations:
>   single-invocation and
>   multiple-invocation. You can
>   distinguish these two forms by their
>   method signatures: the
>   multiple-invocation form has an extra
>   parameter called userState. This form
>   makes it possible for your code to
>   call Method1Async(string param, object
>   userState) multiple times without
>   waiting for any pending asynchronous
>   operations to finish. If, on the other
>   hand, you try to call
>   Method1Async(string param) before a
>   previous invocation has completed, the
>   method raises an
>   InvalidOperationException.
>
> The userState parameter for the
>   multiple-invocation overloads allows
>   you to distinguish among asynchronous
>   operations. You provide a unique value
>   (for example, a GUID or hash code) for
>   each call to Method1Async(string
>   param, object userState), and when
>   each operation is completed, your
>   event handler can determine which
>   instance of the operation raised the
>   completion event.

**My question is:** does the `userState` *have* to be unique? The wording can be construed to make it merely a recommendation, or just pertinent to their example. I do need to pass state to the callback, I just don't need it to be unique. (My application does not need to keep track of each individual instance of the call.) So, is uniqueness a requirement? (Perhaps the asynchronous framework of .NET needs it?)

**Also,** the quoted page is for *event-based* asynchronous operations; does this apply to my case (asynchronous calls using delegates) as well?

I've searched google and SO for a couple of days and have yet to find an answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not apply to your case. `Begin`/`End` are the `IAsyncResult` asynchronous pattern, not the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP).

It affects EAP because usually the implementation uses [`AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.createoperation.aspx), which requires a unique user state. Even in this case, it's (usually) valid for end-user code to pass a `null` user state; the EAP component would replace that with a `new object` when it calls `CreateOperation`.

Comment: Many Thanks! (Such a succinct response to such a verbose question!)